# Why can't I render another page in post method of nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch, sendinblue

I am using sendinblue api to create contacts(emails) which will be seen in the offer page but after I get the success alert nothing happens, I tried many things but I keep getting errors.

The offer page is not getting rendered, I even tried **res.redirect("offer")** but still nothing happens and also I can't use this method since I have to pass the email parameter to the offer page.

This is my index.js

```
const bodyparser = require('body-parser') 
const SibApiV3Sdk = require('sib-api-v3-sdk');
const path = require('path') 
const app = express() 
const env = require('dotenv').config({path: './.env'});
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000 
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:false})) 
app.use(bodyparser.json()) 
// View Engine Setup 
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views')) 
app.set('view engine', 'ejs') 

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/email.html");
})
app.listen(port, function(error){ 
  if(error) throw error 
  console.log("Server created Successfully") 
})


// send email endpoint
app.post("/sendemail", (req, res, next) => {
    const email = req.query.email; 
    console.log(email); 
    let apikey = process.env.SIB_API_KEY
    // auth + setup
    let defaultClient = SibApiV3Sdk.ApiClient.instance; 
    let apiKey = defaultClient.authentications['api-key']; 
    apiKey.apiKey = apikey; 

    // create contact 
    let apiInstance = new SibApiV3Sdk.ContactsApi(); 
    let createContact = new SibApiV3Sdk.CreateContact(); 
    createContact.email = email; 
    createContact.listIds = [2]; 

    apiInstance.createContact(createContact).then((data) => {
      // success 
      res.render('offer',{email:email,  
        publishablekey: Publishable_Key 
        })
  }, function (error) {
      // error
      console.log(error)
      res.status(500); 
      res.send("failure");
  })
})

app.get('/offer', (req, res) => {
  res.render('offer')
});
```

and this is in my email.html page

```
<script>
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = () => {
                // console.log(email.value)
                fetch("/sendemail?email=" + email.value, {
                    method: "POST"
                }).then((res) => {
                    // success
                    alert("success")
                }).catch((err) => {
                    // error 
                    alert(err)
                })}
    </script>
```

Comment: That is not how you render a new page. When you request a page with fetch it gives you the HTML you rendered in the method in the `res` variable. You should put it on the current page by yourself.

Comment: you need return a response of success or failure in express response, then after the then((res) => { }), you should redirect to the offer page

Comment: @lamtacvu Can you specify more clearly?

Comment: @AlexGholamian so are you suggesting me that I cannot render a new page at all?